# Skipping the Shopping Cart

Tags: magento-2.2.5

Is it possible to skip the Shopping Cart (i.e. `/checkout/cart/`)?

So, there's natively 2-steps to buy something: `View and Edit Cart` > `Checkout`

What I'd like to do is remove the `View and Edit Cart` step. The way I see it, there are 2 obvious options to pursue:

1. Create a URL rewrite for `/checkout/cart/` to `/checkout/`
2. Find and hide any buttons/links that point to `/checkout/cart/`

However, I'm looking for a less aggressive option that applies to good practice (if one exists).

**Side-Note**

Anyone curious as to why I'd want to remove this step:

1. I use an OPC that allows for basket editing
2. Minimising the steps to checkout is good practice

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take about good practices, then remove of Shipping cart Page, is not a good Idea for an E-commerce.

> Create a URL rewrite for /checkout/cart/ to /checkout/

You can implement this redirection when you have *item at the cart. If you do not have any item then this redirect create an infinite loop at the system because of empty cart page URL is  /checkout/cart/.*

So, **you have to build a logic like this, when the cart has item rewrite for /checkout/cart/ to /checkout/ will work other scenarios stay at Cart page is good idea**.

> Find and hide any buttons/links that point to /checkout/cart/

I do not think it is a good process of  `Minimising the steps to checkout`.
It is too difficult to find out all redirection which comes to cart page.

*So, in my option, best may be the  First solution but you have to modify some logic of redirection.*